# Creating and binding razor checkboxes from a list

Tags: c#, razor, checkbox

It's been a while since I wrote razor and I'm stuck at creating `checkboxfor` options from a list and make it work. I tried some other answers but none solved the case for me so far.

This is the model I'm using in the view. I'm trying to create checkboxes for Roles.

```
public class AccountRegisterModel
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string emailAddresses { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string passwordConfirm { get; set; }
        public bool? isactive { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string subscriptionKey { get; set; }
        public string SalesPersonReference { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int SalesPersonId { get; set; }
        public int? SalesRegionId { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListModel> Roles { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListModel> Projects { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListModel> SalesRegions { get; set; }
        public int TenantID { get; set; }
        public Guid TenantGuid { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

Type of Roles, `SelectListModel`

```
public class SelectListModel
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string ProjectHierarchyCode { get; set; }
        public string SalesRegionReference { get; set; }
        public int? Depth { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

The way I tried to create the checkboxes

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Roles)
{
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> item.isSelected, new { value = item.Value, id= "chkRole_"+item.Value})
}
```

Models "Roles" list gets populated in the controller and I get 9 unnamed checkboxes on the page. Naming them can be solved with a label so it's not a problem.

Problem is, when I check some of the boxes and hit "Save", chosen roles are not getting posted to the controller. Roles field in the model paramater comes `null`. So I think I have a binding issue.

Comment: Did you try this way?
`@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.isSelected, new { value = item.Value, id= "chkRole_"+item.Value, Name = "CheckBox"})`

Comment: Just tried it now, Roles is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CampusTestResultModelList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td> 
                              @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem=>Model.CampusTestResultModelList[i].RollNumber);

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CampusTestResultModelList[i].StudentName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.CampusTestResultModelList[i].ObtainedMarks, new { @type = "number", min=0, step =1 ,
                             @class = "numeric-class form-control"})


                              @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CampusTestResultModelList[i].TotalMarks)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

Here is example how i done it something is same like this in your case

Answer (score 1):

Try using `For Loop`. I think Razor HTML render is not worked well list of checkboxes.

Here is what you can try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Roles[i].isSelected, new { value = Model.Roles[i].Value })
    }
```

Comment: This posted all roles to action but all of them were isSelected = false although I have chosen two of them

Comment: You may need to update Ids of Hidden field for checkboxes too.

Comment: Or you can remove id from the checkboxes.